# Lumen first api request call take too much time

Tags: laravel, api, rest, lumen, response-time

After I deployed my Lumen project on a shared hosting server, I see that the first request takes too much time to give a response on the contrary of the upcoming requests.

After leaving the application for a while, it does the same thing again.

Please did someone have the same issue?

Ps: sorry for my bad English